# How Can I Get String for another class in Android?

Tags: java, android

I need to get the string variable from one class of my project to another class, 
How Can I get **hashKey** show in MainActivity class

```
public class Functions {   
    public static void printHashKey(Context pContext) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = pContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                Log.e("aaaaa", hashKey);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain little more, the question is unclear

Comment: You can return `hashKey` from this method. And call this method in `MainActivity`.

Comment: I try but I cant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make your function return type string then return your value

   ```
   public class Functions{   
       public static String printHashKey(Context pContext) {

           String hashKey="";
           try {
               PackageInfo info = pContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
               for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                   md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                   hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
                   Log.e("aaaaa", hashKey);
               }
           } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

           } catch (Exception e) {

           }
           return hashKey;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call your method from MainActivity inside onCreate method

   ```
   Functions.printHashKey
   Log.e("Value of printhash key", "" +Functions.printHashKey);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Functions{   
public static String printHashKey(Context pContext) {
String hashKey;

try {
PackageInfo info = pContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(pContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
         hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        Log.e("aaaaa", hashKey);
    }

 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

 } catch (Exception e) {

 }
 return hashKey;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getter() and setters() to solve your problem